# Javascript code doesn't work when embedding a PHP variable into HTML code

Tags: javascript, php

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<title>Planner</title>

<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Variables we need
    var previous    = new Array();
    var lastClicked = '';

    // We are going to attach event listeners, no code at the bottom or anything hard coded...
    function addEvent(obj, evType, fn)
    { 
        if(obj.addEventListener)
        {
            obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, false);
            return true;
        }
        else if(obj.attachEvent)
        {
            var r = obj.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
            return r;
        }
        else
        {
            return false; 
        } 
    }

    // Let's begin when the DOM is ready
    addEvent(window, 'load', begin);

    // Attach the handlers to our selects
    function begin()
    {
        addSelect('numbers');
        addSelect('sm');
        addSelect('sm2');
    }

    // We add a couple of handlers to each
    function addSelect(id)
    {
        var sel = document.getElementById(id);
        addEvent(sel, 'click', whichElement);
        addEvent(sel, 'click', addRemoveClicked);
    }

    // Find which element we are looking at on this click
    function whichElement(e)
    {
        if(!e)
        {
            var e = window.event;
        }

        if(e.target)
        {
            lastClicked = e.target;
        }
        else if(e.srcElement)
        {
            lastClicked = e.srcElement;
        }

        if(lastClicked.nodeType == 3) // Safari bug
        {
            lastClicked = lastClicked.parentNode;
        }
    }

    // Make sure we are displaying the correct items
    function addRemoveClicked(e)
    {
        if(!previous[this.id])
        {
            previous[this.id] = new Array();
        }

        // Remember what has been used
        if(previous[this.id][lastClicked.value] == 1)
        {
            previous[this.id][lastClicked.value] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            previous[this.id][lastClicked.value] = 1;
        }

        var selectBox = document.getElementById(this.id);

        // Add correct highlighting
        for(var i = 0; i < selectBox.options.length; i++)
        {
            selectBox.options[i].selected = '';

            if(previous[this.id][selectBox.options[i].value] == 1)
            {
                selectBox.options[i].selected = 'selected';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
    <select name="numbers[]" id="numbers" multiple="multiple" size="6"> 
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
    </select>

    <select name="classes[]" id="classes" multiple="multiple" size="10"> 
    <?PHP echo $classCode ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed to Next Step" />
    </form>
    </body></html>
```

The value of the `$classCode` variable (string) =

```
<option value="1">201 Intro to Financial Accounting</option> 

<option value="2">202 Intro to Managerial Accounting</option> 

<option value="3">130 Intro to Microeconomics</option> 

<option value="4">320 Principles Bus Finance</option> 

<option value="5">300 Management, &amp; Human Behavior</option>
```

The first multiple select select box (named `numbers[]`) works with Javascript as it should. You're able to click multiple items in the box without having to hold CTRL but the second select box, almost identical to the first, doesn't. I assume because I'm having the program write its own code into a PHP variable, then something happens when I try to embed that PHP variable into the HTML code.

Does anyone know why & how to fix it so the second select box will work the same as the first? You can't click multiple items without having to hold CTRL in the second select box so it's like the javascript functions aren't even registering for the second select box.

**Update 1:** To prove to everyone that it isn't the echo messing things up, I took everything out of an echo statement and it is now only echoing the PHP variable. Still messes up. First select box works, other one that has the PHP variable doesn't.

Excuse the formatting issue. The first 3 chunks of code are meant to be 1.

Comment: Why are you using PHP to print out your entire content?!

Comment: Because the rest of the script is PHP. The content also needs some input from the server-side - thus I used PHP. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: You only need to use PHP for the bits that are... PHP. As for your issue, look at the begin function.

Comment: Looked at it. It's fine. The Java works but only for the first multiple select box where I wrote the code in myself, not for the second box where part of the code is written in by the PHP variable.

Answer (score 0):

Break your echo statement and instead of storing all select box options in an array, render them as they are fetched from the database by iterating thru the result in a while loop. Then the " and \" problem would not arise.  Also you can use ' quotes instead of " within the echo statement.  Here is what I have assumed the situation may be..

```
        <?PHP
    echo "
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
    <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
    <head>

    <title>Planner</title>

    <meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"\" />
    <meta name=\"description\" content=\"\" />

    <script type=\"text/javascript\">

        // Variables we need
        var previous    = new Array();
        var lastClicked = '';

        // We are going to attach event listeners, no code at the bottom or anything hard coded...
        function addEvent(obj, evType, fn)
        { 
            if(obj.addEventListener)
            {
                obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, false);
                return true;
            }
            else if(obj.attachEvent)
            {
                var r = obj.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
                return r;
            }
            else
            {
                return false; 
            } 
        }

        // Let's begin when the DOM is ready
        addEvent(window, 'load', begin);

        // Attach the handlers to our selects
        function begin()
        {
            addSelect('numbers');
            addSelect('sm');
            addSelect('sm2');
        }

        // We add a couple of handlers to each
        function addSelect(id)
        {
            var sel = document.getElementById(id);
            addEvent(sel, 'click', whichElement);
            addEvent(sel, 'click', addRemoveClicked);
        }

        // Find which element we are looking at on this click
        function whichElement(e)
        {
            if(!e)
            {
                var e = window.event;
            }

            if(e.target)
            {
                lastClicked = e.target;
            }
            else if(e.srcElement)
            {
                lastClicked = e.srcElement;
            }

            if(lastClicked.nodeType == 3) // Safari bug
            {
                lastClicked = lastClicked.parentNode;
            }
        }

        // Make sure we are displaying the correct items
        function addRemoveClicked(e)
        {
            if(!previous[this.id])
            {
                previous[this.id] = new Array();
            }

            // Remember what has been used
            if(previous[this.id][lastClicked.value] == 1)
            {
                previous[this.id][lastClicked.value] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                previous[this.id][lastClicked.value] = 1;
            }

            var selectBox = document.getElementById(this.id);

            // Add correct highlighting
            for(var i = 0; i < selectBox.options.length; i++)
            {
                selectBox.options[i].selected = '';

                if(previous[this.id][selectBox.options[i].value] == 1)
                {
                    selectBox.options[i].selected = 'selected';
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form name=\"takenClasses\" method=\"post\" action=\"process.php\">

        <select name=\"numbers[]\" id=\"numbers\" multiple=\"multiple\" size=\"6\"> 
            <option value=\"1\">One</option>
            <option value=\"2\">Two</option>
            <option value=\"3\">Three</option>
            <option value=\"4\">Four</option>
            <option value=\"5\">Five</option>
        </select>

        <select name=\"classes[]\" id=\"classes\" multiple=\"multiple\" size=\"20\"> 
        ";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[course_name] </option>\n";
        }

       echo " 
        </select>
        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Proceed to Next Step\" />
        </form>
        </body></html>";?>
```

Comment: Again, not gonna break the echo just for the sake of improving code. I've also already tried something very similar to this and it wouldn't work. Also, my variable is not an array - it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the code provided, there is absolutely no need to have everything inside an echo. The only thing that needs to be echoed (as far as I can see) is just the `$classCode`. Example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Planner</title>

<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Variables we need
    var previous    = new Array();
    var lastClicked = '';

    // We are going to attach event listeners, no code at the bottom or anything hard coded...
    function addEvent(obj, evType, fn)
    { 
        if(obj.addEventListener)
        {
            obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, false);
            return true;
        }
        else if(obj.attachEvent)
        {
            var r = obj.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
            return r;
        }
        else
        {
            return false; 
        } 
    }

    // Let's begin when the DOM is ready
    addEvent(window, 'load', begin);

    // Attach the handlers to our selects
    function begin()
    {
        addSelect('numbers');
        addSelect('sm');
        addSelect('sm2');
    }

    // We add a couple of handlers to each
    function addSelect(id)
    {
        var sel = document.getElementById(id);
        addEvent(sel, 'click', whichElement);
        addEvent(sel, 'click', addRemoveClicked);
    }

    // Find which element we are looking at on this click
    function whichElement(e)
    {
        if(!e)
        {
            var e = window.event;
        }

        if(e.target)
        {
            lastClicked = e.target;
        }
        else if(e.srcElement)
        {
            lastClicked = e.srcElement;
        }

        if(lastClicked.nodeType == 3) // Safari bug
        {
            lastClicked = lastClicked.parentNode;
        }
    }

    // Make sure we are displaying the correct items
    function addRemoveClicked(e)
    {
        if(!previous[this.id])
        {
            previous[this.id] = new Array();
        }

        // Remember what has been used
        if(previous[this.id][lastClicked.value] == 1)
        {
            previous[this.id][lastClicked.value] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            previous[this.id][lastClicked.value] = 1;
        }

        var selectBox = document.getElementById(this.id);

        // Add correct highlighting
        for(var i = 0; i < selectBox.options.length; i++)
        {
            selectBox.options[i].selected = '';

            if(previous[this.id][selectBox.options[i].value] == 1)
            {
                selectBox.options[i].selected = 'selected';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="takenClasses" method="post" action="process.php">

    <select name="numbers[]" id="numbers" multiple="multiple" size="6"> 
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
    </select>

    <select name="classes[]" id="classes" multiple="multiple" size="20"> 
    <?php echo $classCode; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed to Next Step" />
    </form>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: This is in the middle of a PHP script. In other words, I'm not gonna break the PHP script just so this isn't in an echo statement when it can so effortlessly be in. I also already tried this and I'm getting the same result as I am now - a multiple select box that I need to hold CTRL down on to be able to click multiple items. This isn't an answer to my original question, but merely a suggestion for code improvement

Comment: @KeanuCorreia Like I said, judging from the code you had provided. If this is inside some other script file then add the code so we can get a better grasp on what's happening here because shoving everything inside an echo to be output from the code you had added above isn't the best thing to do as stuff will break on ya pretty easily.

Comment: I updated the OP. Took the code out of the echo and now it's at the bottom of the script and there's only PHP where it should be. Same issue. First multiple select box with "One" "Two", etc. works and I don't need to hold down CTRL but not for the second one with the PHP variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the `begin` function, you attach the handler to the selects by passing the ID attribute of each to the `addSelect` function. You are not doing this for your new select. You simply need to do so:

`addSelect('classes');`